# Vaadin SVGConversor date format

Tags: svg, charts, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin charts from vaadin 7.7.6. When I create a chart where I have several values obtained in different dates, the chart is created correctly. Here I put an image of the obtained result where each value is a pair  to be represented.

[image: Correct chart with dates]

The issue comes, when I want to convert this chart to a PDF file or create a web service that returns this chart as an image to be included elsewhere.

For creating an image from the chart, I use the SVGGenerator as recommended [in the documentation](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-charts-export-from-browser-to-svg-and-pdf). In general, it works really fine and I am able to create PDFs with charts inside. But with this chart I have an issue if the X axis is using **dates**. Here I copy the chart after converted to SVG:

[image: Incorrect chart with dates]

(I have removed some chart controls as the Navigation and the Range selector because are useless in an image or PDF).

At the image we can observe that now in the X axis the dates are not showed correctly. I have checked for several hours the issue, and I am pretty sure that the issue is related to the SVGConversor.

Reading the SVGConversor code, I found a `withLang(String lang)` method. My thought was that maybe, if I set the language, the date is showed correctly (something similar to localization). I am not able to found any documentation of the value needed to this function and therefore, I have tried some values such as `en`, `en_EN`, `en-EN`, `English`, ....  But does not matter the value I put there, always this error is launched:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: SVG generation failed: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: en
```

Still, I am not sure that the `withLang(String lang)` method is the solution to my issue.

The question is: How can I show the correct dates in the X axis of my chart when converted to SVG?

Comment: Note: that converting the xaxis to string is not a good solution, the idea is to maintain the separation between values proportional to the time difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the solution at the end was really easy. The issue is that I have not set the xAxis type. It is not a problem when using the chart in a Vaadin view, but it is mandatory for the SVGConverter to know the axis. Then adding this line of code:

```
        chart.getConfiguration().getxAxis().setType(AxisType.DATETIME);
```

Fix the issue with the SVGConverter. Now the chart is represented correctly in my PDF documents.